# Catch Exception Number in .Net

Tags: .net, exception, try-catch

I am trying to obtain the `Unique/Primary key Exception` number `(2627)` in the *Catch* block.

The exception number is available as the property ***Number*** in `e.InnerException.InnerException` (as shown in the image) [image]

But when I try to retrieve that number, I get - ***'Exception' does not contain a definition for 'Number'***.. (See image with Question mark)

1. Why am I not able to retrieve this number, even though it is clearly a property
2. How do I retrieve the exception number.

Answer (score 5):

That's because `e.InnerException.InnerException` is of type `Exception`, which doesn't have a `Number` property.  In order to access the `Number` property, you need to cast to the expected runtime type of `e.InnerException.InnerException`.

In this case, it looks like the runtime type is a `SqlException`.  If that's the case, then you can express your watch like this (assuming you are using C#):

```
((SqlException)e.InnerException.InnerException).Number
```